# How can I see the parent classes from this doxygen documentation?

Tags: oop, doxygen

How can I see the parent classes from this doxygen documentation ?

I need to know which are the superclasses of a specific class (CPImage).

http://cappuccino.org/learn/documentation/class_c_p_image.html

But I'm only able to list che classes.. without knowing relationships between them.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They/he seem to "forgot" to generate a class diagram (what is possible with doxygen). I only found a diagram for the file reference.

Comment: Ok thanks, so there is no way for me to know which is the parent of CPImage for example ?

Comment: perhaps from the source code, but I couldn't find any hint in the doxygen documentation, sorry :-( ... why program language is that btw?